# "All the apples" or "All apples"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

Which one is correct?

"All the apples on the tree are ripe" or "All apples on the tree are ripe".

Comment: Either is correct.  The first is more idiomatic.

Comment: A deeply philosophical question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSifxC_L9F0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the article "The" when you are referring to specific apples but not all apples.

The apples on this tree are green - *exactly these apples*;

Apples are good for your health - *all apples*;